# Python - Calling __init__ for multiple parent classes

Tags: python-3.x

Edit: I am on **Python 3**.

I have a class `X` that extends both `Y` and `Z`:

```
class X(Y, Z):
    def __init__(self):
    # Call Y's __init__
    # Call Z's __init
    pass
```

I need to call `__init__` on both `Y` and `Z` from the `__init__` on `X`. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am on Python 3.

Comment: That's another one reason, why multiple inheritance - is bad, so how you can ask about best practices in such bad practice?

Comment: OK, I removed the part about best practices. Now what would be your suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends entirely on whether `Y` and `Z` were *designed* to work cooperatively with multiple inheritance.  If they are, then you should be able to just use `super`:

```
class X(Y, Z):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

When I say that `Y` and `Z` need to be designed to work cooperatively with multiple inheritance, I mean that they must also call super in their `__init__` methods:

```
class Y:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Y.__init__')
        super().__init__()

class Z:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Z.__init__')
        super().__init__()
```

They should also have some strategy for handling different arguments since (particularly the constructor) of a class frequently differ in which keyword arguments that they accept.  At this point, it's worth reading [Super considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) and [Super considered harmful](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) to understand some common idioms and pitfalls regarding super.

If you don't know whether `Y` and `Z` were designed for cooperative multiple inheritance, then the safest recourse is to assume that they weren't.

---

**If the classes aren't designed to work with cooperative multiple inheritance**, then you need to start stepping lightly (**you're in dangerous waters**).  You *can* call each `__init__` individually:

```
class X(Y, Z):
    def __init__(self):
        Y.__init__(self)
        Z.__init__(self)
```

But really **it's probably better to not use multiple inheritance and instead choose a different paradigm** (e.g. composition).

Comment: In my case, the parents are - `threading.Thread` and `logging.Handler` - how do I check if they are designed to work cooperatively in multiple inheritance?

Comment: As far as I can tell, [`threading.Thread`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/threading.py#l738) does not.

Comment: @masnun The question you need to ask yourself is: why do you want to inherit from both of them? You are mixing unrelated concepts. It would be cleaner to use a class with both of them as fields (or some other clean pattern).

Comment: @mgilson I guess `Handler` also doesn't use `super`. I can see it calls `Filterer.__init__(self)` in it's own `__init__`. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @freakish You have an excellent point. I am going to try and separate the concerns in two classes and glue them together. In case that doesn't work, I will have to depend on multiple inheritance.

Comment: @masnun I can assure it will work. Plus you won't have to deal with weird issues around multiple inheritance. This should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: @mgilson, could you (or anyone else) explain why the last solution (i.e. calling `Y.__init__()` directly rather than using `super()`) is dangerous?

Comment: Let's assume that `Y` also has a base-class (`Q`) and `Y` calls `super().__init__()` to make sure that it (implicitly) calls `Q.__init__()`.  Depending on the method resolution order, `Y`'s `super().__init__()` might actually call `Z.__init__` instead of `Q.__init__`.  If  `Z.__init__` also `super`s, then you'll call `Z.__init__` twice (once here and once explicitly later).  If `Z.__init__` doesn't `super`, then you'll likely skip `Q.__init__` entirely.

Answer (score 4):

Generally there is no other way then to call `Y.__init__(self)` and `Z.__init__(self)` directly. It's the only way to ensure that both constructors are called **at least once**.

However in some weird (or normal, depending on how you look at it) cases this can lead to very unintuitive results where base constructors are called multiple times:

```
class Y:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Y')
        super().__init__()

class Z:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Z')
        super().__init__()

class X(Y, Z):
    def __init__(self):
        print('X')
        Y.__init__(self)
        Z.__init__(self)

X()
```

Results in

```
X
Y
Z
Z
```

So in that case  `super().__init__()` in `X` (instead of both `.__init__()` calls) seems natural and will work correctly. However it will fail if `Y` and `Z` don't call `super().__init__()` as well. In that case you will only call one of the constructors.

So generally there is no way to solve your issue correctly without knowing implementation of base classes.

YARtAMI = Yet Another Reason to Avoid Multiple Inheritance

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. In my case none of the parent classes have any common ancestor.

Comment: @masnun They don't have to have. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Is there any explanation for understanding why the first call `super().__init__()` in Y triggers the Z.__init__()??? I understood Y and Z inherit from `object`, so I can't understand why the first 'Z' print on screen