# Python: Is it possible to merge two __init__ after multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, class, oop

I want my **class Parents(Mom, Dad)** to inheritance **init** attributes from two previous classes so then my input will require me to write mom_name and dad_name. Can someone suggest me how to do this?

```
class Mom(object):
    def __init__(self, mom_name):
        self.mom_name = mom_name

class Dad(object):
    def __init__(self, dad_name):
        self.dad_name = dad_name

class Parents(Mom, Dad):
    pass

par = Parents('Mom', 'Dad')
print(par.mom_name)
print(par.dad_name)
```

Comment: Both your parent classes need to call `super()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Calling \_\_init\_\_ for multiple parent classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415085/python-calling-init-for-multiple-parent-classes)

Answer (score 4):

you can implement it this way

```
class Mom(object):
    def __init__(self, mom_name):
        self.mom_name = mom_name

class Dad(object):
    def __init__(self, dad_name):
        self.dad_name = dad_name

class Parents(Mom, Dad):
    def __init__(self, mom_name, dad_name):
        Mom.__init__(self, mom_name)
        Dad.__init__(self,dad_name)

par = Parents('Mom', 'Dad')
print(par.mom_name)
print(par.dad_name)
```

output

```
Mom
Dad
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this.

```py
class Parents(Mom, Dad):

     def __init__(self, mom_name, dad_name):
         super(Mom, self).__init__(mom_name)
         super(Dad, self).__init__(dad_name)
```

Edit 1 :

The code above doesn't work, a suitable way will be to subclass Dad from Mum and then paste it to parents like this.

```py
class Mom(object):
    def __init__(self, mom_name):
        self.mom_name = mom_name

class Dad(Mom):
    def __init__(self, dad_name, **kw):
        self.dad_name = dad_name
        super(Dad, self).__init__(**kw)

class Parents(Dad):

    def __init__(self, mom_name, dad_name):
        super(Parents, self).__init__(mom_name=mom_name, dad_name=dad_name)

p = Parents("mumy", "dady")       
print(p.mom_name)
print(p.dad_name)
```

Comment: @gst Yes, doesn't work, I'm looking on why, because I'm pretty sure that we do something like this.

Comment: I think this is how you'd do it Python 2, not sure though.

Comment: calling super on multiple inheritance classes  is bad idea

Comment: @temmo When I will understand why, I will update my awser.

Comment: i am just saying it is bad idea, for this sample code it will work no doubt, think of maintaining such dew couple of classess

Comment: @temmo Nope, it doesent work, when calling two time super I can't get both attribute.

Comment: why call super two time, one must know how the super is use and use case also why using inheritance and how to implement a clean code structure